# Bootstrap 3 Mobile Menu with icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to **brbcoding** in the comments. Updated JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Bootstrap714/RfsS9/14/

He mentioned something about transitions. How would I go about doing that or what is the best route.

**Here is where I am at:**

I am using Bootstrap 3 to build a menu. Bootstrap comes with a nice collapse feature for the menu when viewed on mobile. It takes the whole menu and puts it in a button to collapse. IE: if you have "link dropdown-link dropdown-link" there will be one button and it will toggle a dropdown with those links.

**My question is:**

Can those 3 links become each their own toggle buttons and control their own dropdowns. If you create multiple collapse toggle buttons. the toggle button opens the drop down to show the link. Then you must click on that link to open the sub-dropdown.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#settings">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inbox">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#">Brand</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">AL</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Popular Tags <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left hidden-xs" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->  

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="inbox">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="inbox" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i> Inbox<span class="badge">42</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="settings">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i> Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->  
    </div>
    </div>
```

So basically, when in mobile, you can see the two toggle buttons. Is there a way for that toggle button to open to the sub menu instead of clicking the link and then having it open.

how it is now: toggle button, click link, then it opens
what i would like: toggle button, opens right to the drop down.

Comment: So you want the inbox and settings to already be dropped down when the two navbar toggles are clicked?

Comment: I think that is correct. Ex: if i clicked on the inbox toggle. i would like it to open to the drop down showing "messages 1". Instead of clicking the toggle button, then clicking the envelope link and then seeing the "messages 1"

Comment: If you can pin down the event that happens when a user clicks on the toggle button then all you need to do is add the class `open` to the `li.dropdown`. That class gets added to the element when it's clicked currently.

Comment: You could do something like... `$('.navbar').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $(e.target).find('li.dropdown').addClass('open');
});`, you'd just have to do a little transition stuff to make it less jerky. You'd obviously also store a reference to the open one and remove that class on click/open/etc... Don't really have time to work on it but here's a quick demo - http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/RfsS9/9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RfsS9/8/ Take a look at this fiddle I had to wrap the addClass in a setTimeout because of the animation. I'm not sure if there are better ways, but there is also a problem with changing screen size and the drop down staying open.